# How to get value from number tagged file and compare it?

Tags: c#, extract

hi i'm trying to extract values from this tagged file
here is the file

```
  0
LINE
  5
1C1CBD
330
1C1ADB
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0-FD
 62
     9
370
    -2
100
AcDbLine
 10
53740.73468153231
 20
-190253.3098529756
 30
0.0
 11
53690.49919802765
 21
-190166.2994431953
 31
0.0
  0
```

you can see that there is a hexadecimal number below "LINE", is there anyway i can extract it into some list?

like
VALUE = 1C1CBD

## NOTE: the file consist more than one of this kind of pattern

and then how can i get the maximum value?

**EDIT 1**

i see that "5" can be found by using regex "\s\s5" can i use this?

Comment: How exactly do you want the list to look like? How does that pettern work?

Comment: You tagged this post as xml, but I don't see any XML here.  It's simple to handle this particular case; however, providing you with a general solution that will work for all of your files won't be possible without knowing more about the structure of your files.

Comment: right, my lecturer said that there are many types of xml, and i think this is the one of xml that doesn't use (){}[] instead it use group codes as the tags.

Comment: @GammaSatriaKurniawan Your lecturer is wrong, or you misunderstood. That file is not XML. XML is standardized by the W3C and is based on SGML (ISO 8879).

Comment: depends if you can come up with good rules to find them, and if those rules don't clash.   eg, in the case so far, does the rule, 'After "LINE", extract the second number as a hex number'   work for the whole file?

Comment: @GammaSatriaKurniawan, this most certainly is not a kind of XML. All XML uses `<tags>`.

Comment: the structure is only like that, because i have divide every section and come up with this structure, and list is like value[0]=1C1CBD,value[1]=1C1CBE,value[2]=1C1CBF etc

Comment: Well, until you can tell use what the structure is (and it is NOT XML), it's going to be practically impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your feedback i have been able to complete what i want
here is the code

```
string[] handle = originalString.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        List<string> hexa = new List<string>();
        for (var a = 1; a <= handle.Count() - 1; a++)
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(handle[a], @"^\s\s5"))
            {
                hexa.Add(handle[a + 1]);
            }
        }

        List<int> HexaToInt = new List<int>();
        foreach (string valueHexa in hexa)
        {
            int intHexaValue = int.Parse(valueHexa, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            HexaToInt.Add(intHexaValue);
        }

        int maximumHexa = HexaToInt.Max();
        string hexValue = maximumHexa.ToString("X");
```

it is possible afterall to extract the hexadecimal value from the handle group codes

Answer (score -1):

It is totally **impossible**.

No way to catch characters and extract what you need.

You have to organize  the structure of this file better.

Comment: Why would it be impossible? Organizing the file better might be a good idea, but certainly not necessary.

Comment: This structure is unstable. You never know which elements you have to extract. It goes from AcDbLine Methods  http://docs.autodesk.com/ACDMAC/2012/ENU/ObjectARX%20Reference/index.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=%21%21MEMBERTYPE_Methods_AcDbLine.html

Comment: then can you just tell how can i use regex to match the "  5" because when i use "\s\s5" it also match with the "     5"

Comment: @GammaSatriaKurniawan That's a problem! :) I cannot see any chance to match values in this file structure... May be I am wrong...

Comment: right now i am trying to use the pattern of this structure, as you can see there are 2 whitespace before the handle tag, then the hexadecimal value that i want to extract then below that value there is 330 group codes